# Cheap Intel based SBC

Tags: sbc, cheap, intel

I am getting tired of cross compilation.

I am looking for:

- a cheap  (sub $100, preferably sub $50) Intel based SBC
- with some form of flash/eMMC (but not just micro SD card)
- a UART (two would be nice)
- and GPIO
- with a selection of displays available (from 3 lines of text x32 chars to about a 7” colo(u)r display)
- plus a 4x4 keypad, but I reckon the GPIO can take care of that
- and the ability to drive some stepper motors (GPIO again)
- WiFi would be a bonus
- single core is just fine

I don’t need the following, though won’t reject anything with, if it doesn’t affect the price too much:

- multicore
- hi-res graphics / GPU
- sound
- camera
- Bluetooth
- SATA

To summarize, I am looking for something like a Raspberry Pi Zero W, with an some flash storage and an Intel processor which will let me develop on Windows / Linux without cross-compilation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cheap Intel SBCs

There is not much choice:

- [UP board](https://up-shop.org/up-boards/272-up-board.html)
- [Atomic Pi](https://web.archive.org/web/20200715220148/https://dlidirect.com/products/atomic-pi)

```
╭───────╥────────────┬─────────────╮
│ Name  ║  UP board  │  ATOMIC Pi  │
╞═══════╬════════════╪═════════════╡
│ Price ║ > $ 109    │ > $ 35      │
│ Flash ║ 16 - 64 GB │ 16GB        │
│  UART ║ 1          │ 1           │
│  GPIO ║ 40         │ 26          │
└───────╨────────────┴─────────────┘
```

A use-full Atomic Pi wiki [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Atomic_Pi/wiki).

Comment: I will leave this open for a day or tow, but am confident that we already have a winner. That Atomic Pi looks ***excellent*** !! Probably too much for me, to be honest :-)  A killer will be if there is any way to use Pi/Arduino hats/shields; even if not, this is great. Thanx a 1,000,000

Comment: I bought an Atomic PI !  Yay!!   ***BUT***, and a rally big but(t) - [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Atomic_Pi/comments/bnvtq8/atomic_pi_leftover_from_mayfield_robotics/) says that the only reason that the Atomci Pi is so cheap is that they bought the boards job-lot from a failed Bosch project, so when they are old sold either there will be no more or they will be much more expensive. I still don't regret buying it, though -only $33 !!

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2019/06/06/the-atomic-pi-is-it-worth-it/